# Numpy - Matrix Generation from list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the following list of `np.array`:

```
dataset = [np.random.normal(r_mean/(p*t), r_vol/t/np.sqrt(p), n) \
           for t in rule]
```

I want to transform it into an 2D `np.array` (ie. a matrix). I could use `np.asarray`, but  (I believe) it would be inefficient.

Also, each `np.random.normal(r_mean/(p*t), r_vol/t/np.sqrt(p), n)` is meant to be a column of the resulting matrix, not a row (ie. I'd have to transpose `np.asarray(dataset)`).

What is the best way of achieving the result ?

Comment: Loops are usually fast in NumPy. Have you considered something like: `dataset = np.zero((dim1,dim2))` and `for nt, t in enumerate(rule): dataset[nt,:] = np.random.normal(r_mean/(p*t), r_vol/t/np.sqrt(p), n)`.

Comment: Could you tweak the generation of `dataset` to make something that is better for concatenation, or is it fixed?

Comment: Better for concatenation ?

Comment: Why do you think `asarray` will be inefficient?

Comment: Because unless asarray creates a pointer to the dataset value (which I highly doubt it does), the values will have to be copied over to another object.

Comment: Unless you use a (nearly useless) object dtype, any array construction will require a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use broadcasting to create `dataset` with a single call to `numpy.random.normal`. Instead of using a list comprehension, make `rule` a numpy array and use it where you have `t` in your expression, and request a sample with size `(n, len(rule))`:

```
In [66]: r_mean = 1.0

In [67]: r_vol = 3.0

In [68]: p = 2.0

In [69]: rule = np.array([1.0, 100.0, 10000.0])

In [70]: n = 8

In [71]: dataset = np.random.normal(r_mean/(p*rule), r_vol/rule/np.sqrt(p), size=(n, len(rule)))

In [72]: dataset
Out[72]: 
array([[  7.44295301e-01,  -1.57786106e-03,  -1.85518458e-04],
       [ -2.37293991e+00,  -2.27875859e-02,   3.38182239e-04],
       [  2.01362974e+00,   5.93566418e-02,  -3.00178175e-04],
       [  2.52533022e+00,   8.15380813e-03,   1.82511343e-04],
       [  7.32980563e-01,   2.67511372e-02,  -1.95965258e-04],
       [  2.91958598e+00,  -1.36314059e-02,   2.45200175e-04],
       [ -4.43329724e+00,  -5.85052629e-02,  -1.75796458e-04],
       [ -2.45005431e-01,  -1.68543495e-02,   1.69715542e-04]])
```

If you are unsure that the columns correctly match the parameters, we can test a large sample:

```
In [73]: n = 100000
```

Create `mu` and `std` so we can see the requested means and standard deviations:

```
In [74]: mu = r_mean/(p*rule)

In [75]: std = r_vol/rule/np.sqrt(p)
```

Generate the data:

```
In [76]: dataset = np.random.normal(mu, std, size=(n, len(rule)))
```

Here's the `mu` that we requested:

```
In [77]: mu
Out[77]: array([  5.00000000e-01,   5.00000000e-03,   5.00000000e-05])
```

And here's what we got in the sample:

```
In [78]: dataset.mean(axis=0)
Out[78]: array([  4.95672937e-01,   5.08624034e-03,   5.02922664e-05])
```

Here are the desired standard deviations:

```
In [79]: std
Out[79]: array([  2.12132034e+00,   2.12132034e-02,   2.12132034e-04])
```

And here's what we got:

```
In [80]: dataset.std(axis=0)
Out[80]: array([  2.11258192e+00,   2.12437161e-02,   2.11784163e-04])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ds = np.empty((dataset[0].size, len(dataset)), dtype=dataset[0].dtype)
for i in range(ds.shape[1]):
    ds[:, i] = dataset[i]
```

but only do that if you must precompute the `dataset` list first.

Else use a generator:

```
ds = np.empty((n, len(rule)))
dataset = (np.random.normal(r_mean/(p*t), r_vol/t/np.sqrt(p), n) for t in rule)
for i, d in enumerate(dataset):
    ds[:, i] = d
```

Comment: See Warrens answer for an even more performant solution, creating the final `(n, len(rule))` matrix simultaneously.